# How can I handle ParserErrors and keep parsing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading in multiple CSV files, and if I catch a ParserError I want to log that it had an error but skip concatenating that file to my data frame. I have found a way to read all the files given to me, but since I used list comprehension I am finding it hard to catch my error in a way that doesn't cause my program to exit or a way to not append it to my data frame. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I have also noticed that this only gives me one column so that may be causing an issue as well.

code:

```
def read_files():
    path = 'data'
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
    try:
        df = pd.concat(map(lambda file: pd.read_csv(file, error_bad_lines=True), files))
    except ParserError as pe:
        # do something here
```

Comment: As an aside, what is the point of using `map()` and a lambda here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import logging
for file in files:
    try:
        df = pd.concat(df, pd.read_csv(file, error_bad_lines=True))
    except ParseError as pe:
        logging.error(pe)
        continue
```